# No more days left on my Schengen stay. Can I transit through EU airport back to the US?

Tags: schengen, transit, airports, airport-transfer, eu

I don't have any more days left on my Schengen stay. Could I still transit through an EU airport back to my home country(US)?

I would only transfer through one EU airport.

Would enter EU from a non-EU country and then connect in one airport and then enter the US.

Comment: But as an example: Zurich

Comment: Of course you mean to do that with both flights on a single ticket, right?

Comment: The Schengen rules are widely misunderstood.  Off-by-one errors are common, and people often do not understand how to calculate multiple visits or how long they need to remain outside the Schengen area before they can return.

Answer (score 9):

As a US citizen you can usually transit in the Schengen area without having to enter the country/Schengen area, but there are a few airports which do not have an international area or make you leave one part of the airport transiting into and out of the Schengen area and there you may run into problems.

Another problem might be cancelled flights, where alternatives are via other Schengen countries, or making you stay overnight in a city where the airport closes in the night.

Best check with the actual airport or avoid the Schengen area. (Or check whether you are really out of days, one single day will do for a two Schengen airports transit, two for an overnight stay.)

This is all assuming you have one single ticket for the whole trip. Self connecting is not possible as airlines will only transport you if you are allowed into the country they see as the final destination.